# upload/run laravel project using cpanel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I need to run the project using cpanel. all the database detail are changed and up-to-date, also I have manually imported the database to cpanel.

What I have done so far:

uploaded the whole project to the server via filezilla.
then i created a .htaccess file with following content so every request will go to public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

still I have a message saying `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: Try change config/app.php -> `'debug' => true` to get more info. Or maybe laravel.log file.

Comment: well now it says `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.` and since I am in cpanel i cannot run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: @Regolith If your host doesn't offer SSH access, get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add a valid key. In `config/app.php`:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'MyKeyWith32Chars'), //<--- ADD here a key with 32 random chars 
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Optionally,  add in your `.env`:

```
APP_KEY=MyKeyWith32Chars
```